# Does preparation of food change the nutritional content with respect to fat type?

Tags: food-science, fat, nutrient-composition

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge in how a fat comes to be saturated, and perhaps therein lies the answer to this question. However, due to my wife's gall stones I need to remove hard to digest fats from my cooking routine. In addition to buying fewer raw ingredients that have high saturated, hydrogenated, or trans- fats, I want to be sure that food preparation methods do not change the chemical structure of fats that I do happen to be working with.

I may just be over-thinking this, but in cases of suspending one fat in another, emulsification, etc I wanted to know if there are any methods I should avoid due to the chemical changes they entail. For instance, deep-frying foods (which typically use the fats I hope to avoid) is said to make them difficult to digest.

Please list any others that do; or let me know if I'm just being a worry wart.

Comment: By the way, I hope you are operating on the advice of a medical professional here, because even with all of the criticism around saturated fats (a lot of which may be valid), one criticism I definitely *haven't* heard is that they are more "difficult to digest".  Concern tends to be more over the *long-term* health effects.

Comment: @Aar working with the surgeon who was originally going to remove her gallbladder, we were given recommendations to avoid foods that impair liver health and to lower fat consumption generally and improve fiber consumption. He also recommended taking standard steps to reduce cholesterol and we are eventually meeting with a dietician to get some more tangible guidelines.

Comment: Fair enough @mfg.  Just wanted to make sure, since I'm so used to seeing other people acting as their own doctors and dieticians.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with me being responsible for my own diet. Why would I ever yield up that responsibility into less capable (and no doubt profiteering) hands?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simple answer is no, you cannot convert monounsaturated/polyunsaturated fats into saturated fats through cooking alone.

Before I can even begin to answer in detail, I have to start by pointing out that "saturated" and "unsaturated" fat is already an oversimplification.  These are *very rough* classifications of fats and the chemical reality is far more nuanced.  I'd encourage you read the Wikipedia entry on [Fatty acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid) for a relatively basic explanation.

Fatty acids are *actually* classified, chemically, in three different ways:

1. The existence of **double bonds** (CH=CH) somewhere in the molecular structure.  Fatty acids with double bounds are *unsaturated*.  Fatty acids with single bonds only are *saturated*.
2. The **chain length** (number of Carbon-Hydrogen groups).  Another distinguishing characteristic of *saturated* fatty acids is that they are generally (maybe always) *long-chain*. The reverse is not necessarily true, however; not all long-chain fatty acids are saturated.
3. The **configuration**, either *cis* or *trans*.  Trans fatty acids are not actually a different *type* of fat in the same sense as saturated vs. unsaturated; they are actually unsaturated fatty acids, just in a different configuration.

Although certain studies suggest that it is *possible* to create TFAs from edible oils with prolonged heat, it is also *extremely difficult*, to the extent that it's nearly impossible to do in meaningful quantities by accident.  I will refer you to [this study of heat-induced cis/trans isomerization](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/221/4617/1256.abstract) which says that after **8 hours** of heating at 180° C, the researchers found up to 6.5 mg of trans isomers per 1.0 g of oil, which comes out to a grand total of **0.65%** by mass.  This is practically nil as far as a home cook is concerned - these quantities only matter if you're doing commercial processing of vegetable oils, or *maybe* if you're using the oil for deep-frying and you reuse it *dozens* of times (far beyond what any experienced fry cook would recommend).

The study also says that edible oils (i.e. the ones you cook with) experienced *less* isomerization than other kinds.  So really, the amount of isomerization you're going to get (conversion of the "good" cis isomers to "bad" trans isomers) is minuscule and simply insignificant as far as mainstream baking or frying applications are concerned.  So forget about trans fats.

Can you create saturated fats?  That would effectively mean breaking down the double bonds into single bonds.  In order to do that, you need to *add* hydrogen (that's why saturated fatty acids are "saturated" - more hydrogen).

**There's a name for this process**, which you actually stumbled upon in your question.  It's called **[Hydrogenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_peroxidation)**.  It's adding hydrogen atoms to an unsaturated (double-bonded) fatty acid.

Hydrogenation requires a *substrate* (involving benzene or some other hydrocarbon), a *hydrogen source* (that's pure, dangerous, H<sub>2</sub> gas), and a *catalyst* (heavy metal).  My guess is that your kitchen has *none* of those things, unless you're cooking in a chemistry lab.  So there is simply *no chance* for you to accidentally hydrogenate your oils.

What you really need to be more worried about with oils (unsaturated fats) is [lipid peroxidation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_peroxidation).  That's the oxidative breakdown and, eventually, **rancidity** of fats, and polyunsaturated fats are particularly prone to this.  **Heat is a catalyst for peroxidation**, so if you "burn" your oil (or other fats), you may end up creating the same sorts of free radicals normally associated with rancidity due to improper storage.  The long-term effect of these free radicals is not firmly established but the consensus seems to be that [they aren't good for you in the long term](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/221/4617/1256.abstract) (cancer risk and so on).

So don't worry about *converting* your oils when you cook with them.  It's practically impossible.  You should be more concerned with *overheating* them or letting them go rancid in storage.

Comment: I notice a downvote; if I'm over-simplifying or if my answer is wrong somewhere, please let me know where.  I want this to be strictly factual and correct.

Comment: I take exception to the strong claim that one can't convert cis-configuration bonds to trans- by heating. Check out [Real-Time Monitoring of Thermally Induced Trans Fats in Corn Oil Using the FatIR™ Oil Analysis System](http://www.bkinstruments.co.kr/html/pdf_file/applications/Oil-Analysis-by-ATR.pdf). Admittedly I am not a professional in this field, but the concept of the "tail" of the molecule turning over so one of the two hydrogen molecules opposite the double bond moves to the opposite side is not unreasonable.

Comment: P.S. I think there's a misconception in calling cooking "non-chemical." Cooking in many ways is all about chemistry. While most of it may be the rearrangement of whole molecules in relation to each other, I don't think it's accurate to say the molecules are themselves never changed. For a simple example, doesn't the yeast organism produce new molecules rather than just rearrange existing ones? That's cooking.

Comment: @Emtucifor: Yeast is alive, for one thing, so you're really talking about a biological process, not a chemical one.  I take your point; however, chemical reactions require chemical reactions and simply heating or mixing oils isn't going to cause that (except for the heat breakdown, i.e. peroxidation mentioned earlier).  I didn't mean to imply that cooking *in general* was non-chemical, just the specific actions being talked about in this question.

Comment: First, do you mind replying to the more important point about trans fats being produced by heating? Second, hold on there: you said "any other culinary process" which you equated to "non-chemical". But such an exclusion seems artificial. I'm not convinced that "culinary processes" can't cause chemical reactions. Do you have a source for this? Something as simple as baking soda + vinegar can make new molecules. Restricting that statement now to "only the processes mentioned in this post" seems an afterthought. Please understand this isn't an attack, just an inquiry.

Comment: @Emtucifor: Baking soda and vinegar is another chemical reaction that requires multiple ingredients.  I was referring to processes that are entirely thermal or mechanical in nature; mixing, frying, baking, etc.  My explanation isn't an afterthought, I'm genuinely surprised that somebody would be reading into my statements beyond the context of the question.  Anyway, as to the more important point you're referring to, I've been reading that link and trying to make sense of what they're saying.  Once I understand it all, I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: Well, @Emtucifor, I've read through it top to bottom and the biggest thing missing is some reference to actual *mass*.  Everything is given in spectroscopic terms, specifically in absorption units, and I have no idea if the numbers actually corresponding to anything significant from a nutritional perspective.  If 3 hours of direct heat convert 1% of the cis bonds to trans, then my original statement is true that peroxidation is going to be a much bigger concern.  I need to try to find a source that gives meaningful numbers.

Comment: Alright, I'm done with my research.  Everything I've looked at says that yes, isomerization does occur, but in quantities so tiny that the issue is virtually immaterial to a cook.  So I've updated my post to include all the fine details but my conclusion remains essentially the same; trans fats don't matter when you're cooking with non-hydrogenated vegetable oils.

Comment: @Aaronut: I’m probably misunderstanding you, and I’m sorry to barge in like that. But … cooking is essentially *nothing but* chemical transformation: frying, baking, …. All those are just fancy names for multiple chemical transformations happening, e.g. protein denaturation and Maillard reaction. The whole point of heating food is to elicit a chemical reaction. Furthermore, you stated that a biological reaction isn’t a chemical one, which is also false: Biological reactions are *special* chemical reactions which use an enzyme as a catalyst.

Comment: @Konrad Biology is just an application of chemistry, and chemistry is just an application of physics, and pure physics is just math. However, this isn't math.stackexchange.com, so let's not nitpick too much, as long as the answer is essentially correct.

Comment: @Bob: yes, I was aware of that. My impression was that Aaronut wasn’t.

Comment: @Konrad: Let's not get too wrapped up in that minor detail at this point, seeing as how that particular verbiage has already been removed from the answer and replaced with a much more detailed analysis of isomerization.

Comment: @Aaronut: FYI, I liked the answer, and upvoted it. As far as I see, it describes the whole process and the risks fairly. I just noticed that the discussion in the commends seemed to operate on the premise of a false dichotomy.

Comment: @Aaronut Your update is great. Thanks for being responsive. By the way, you have my upvote. So let me ask you a question: what oils DO you recommend cooking with? My understanding is that cooking with animal fats or tropical oils _because they are more saturated_ is more healthy, as they are more resistant to damage. Not to mention that I don't believe the lipid hypothesis anyway (that cholesterol and saturated fat cause heart disease). I suppose this is worthy of a new question... ?

Comment: @Emtucifor: We try to stay away from those health topics here, since nutrition is really quite a different field from the culinary arts. If you're asking me my opinion (and I won't claim it to be anything more than that), I think it's yet another hypothesis that has merit and bears further investigation, but the scientific community *is still gathering data* and simply hasn't reached any definitive conclusion. What that means to me is that I'll cook with whichever fat is actually most appropriate for *cooking* a particular dish (except trans fats), and not concern myself with unknowns.

Comment: My experience is that every politicized "scientific" debate is essentially the same; in the non-scientific world you invariably have two violently-opposed sides arguing about whether the answer is "yes" or "no", while actual scientists in the field investigate *facets* of the problem. There *is* no simple yes or no answer, most of the time. Saturated fats seem to have health benefits, unsaturated fats seem to have other health benefits. Check out this link: [Fats you need](http://www.benbest.com/health/essfat.html).

Answer (score 6):

Fats don't generally change structure as a result of cooking. As you heat up a fat, it's structure loosens, but doesn't fundamentally change. (Cocoa fat is an exception.) So no, how you cook your food will not create more unsaturated fat (unless you're cooking it in unsaturated fat).

I think deep frying makes foods harder to digest not because it makes chemical changes to the food, but because it 1) dries out the food and 2) introduces more fat from the cooking oil.

If you want more info on what saturated and unsaturated mean, and which fats are less saturated, [On Food and Cooking has a short section](http://books.google.com/books?id=bKVCtH4AjwgC&lpg=PP1&dq=on%20food%20and%20cooking&pg=PA798#v=onepage&q&f=false) with lots of good info.

Comment: Counterintuitive though it may be, deep fat frying, if properly done introduces less fat than other fat based cooking methods.  That is because it is cooked at a higher temperature, so it sits in the fat not as long as other methods.  The outward pressure of moisture escaping the food works to limit the oil seeping in.  The problem with deep fat frying is that it is rarely done with the healthier types of oil like olive oil (doubt that you could).  Also items deep fat fried are almost always coated with a batter of some type.

Comment: @Bill: I think it's really the batter that's the issue.  There are plenty of oils with high smoke points that are low in saturated fats - sunflower oil, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if the question is "Can I turn a monounsaturated or polyunsaturated fat into a saturated fat through cooking?" then the answer is "No, you can not."

Answer (score 3):

The process of saturating or unsaturating a fat involves breaking double bonds and adding hydrogen to the molecule. The more double bonds, the more UN saturated the fat.

This is all determined by the initial production of the fat. Animal fats are more saturated and certain 'desirable' fats are LESS saturated when they are created. There is no way that I know of to change this DURING the cooking process.

Extreme heat methods will make some chemical changes, but saturating the fat would involve breaking the bonds and adding hydrogen, and when this is done commercially it requires catalysts and other specific conditions.